# Continuously "Response: Not available" Windows 10 event logs

Tags: windows-10, event-log, language-pack

I continuously gets the following event log in Windows 10 ver. 1809 LTSC:

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: CbsPackageServicingFailure2
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: 10.0.17763.164
P2: Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Basic-en-gb-Package
P3: 10.0.17763.1
P4: amd64
P5: unknown
P6: 80072efd
P7: CBS Other
P8: Absent
P9: Absent
P10: FodHelper(LanguageFeaturesOnDemand)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems some or all event logs which include the `Response: Not available` will create some event-log-reports, dump-files etc. in these folders:
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\`
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\`
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\`
Especially the last one!

Even though the problem, which originally caused the event log in the first place, was solved these event-log-reports will continuously recreate themselves including new event logs with the same content.

Another example of an event log which continuously recreate itself is:

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: WSQLBackup.exe
P2: 0.0.0.0
P3: 5be769ed
P4: KERNELBASE.dll
P5: 10.0.17763.615
P6: b6cb145b
P7: e0434352
P8: 0000000000039129
```

Actually on this system the program `WSQLBackup.exe` once crashed and caused this event log. The program was deleted long time ago and no other task or process was trying to call this program, but still this event log was recreated for every 20-30 minutes.

Solution to stop this even-log-looping is to DELETE the content of these three folders.